# Given $x(t) = u(t)$ and $h(t) = \cos(\pi t)u(t)$, how do we find the response $y(t)$?

Tags: integration

Given $x(t) = u(t)$ and $h(t) = \cos(\pi t)u(t)$, find the response $y(t)$.

$y(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}h(\tau)x(t−\tau)\, d\tau=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(t−\tau)\, d\tau $

I can solve this if I can plot, $u(t−\tau)$.

Comment: I can solve this if i can plot, \$u(t−τ)\$.

Comment: @RajeshKSingh: For all τ < t,  u(t−τ) = 0.  For all τ >= t, u(t−τ) = 1.  The plot is a line along the x-axis (y=0) up to but not including x=τ, then a step discontinuity at x=τ, then a line y=1 going right to infinity.  Any good electric circuit analysis textbook should explain this, as it is a critical concept for transient analysis of RLC circuits.

Comment: This was tagged "untagged". I retagged it, "integration". If someone has a better tag idea, go for it.

Comment: I don't see why the integral isn't $\int_{0}^{\infty}cos(\pi\tau)u(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau$.

Comment: @Max: You are both right, because for $\tau>0$, $u(\tau)\equiv 1$. (Assuming that he is using $u$ to represent the unit step function.)

Comment: What's the underlying system (i.e., the ODE) here?

Comment: This really belongs on dsp.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally use Laplace transform to evaluate these; using convolution can get really cumbersome.

Recall that Laplace transform of convolution of two functions is equal to the product of Laplace transforms of the individual functions. So, in order to get y(t), we need to find the Laplace transforms of x(t) and h(t), multiply them and then do the Inverse transform on the result.

$$
X(s) = L\{x(t)\}\\
H(s) = L\{h(t)\}\\
y(t) = {L}^{-1}\{X(s).H(s)\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if you are asking whether your integral for $y(t)$ is correct, or, assuming it is correct, how to compute it and then plot the response. I'll proceed assuming the latter since you don't tell us enough information to accurately judge the former.

$$y(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}h(\tau)x(t−\tau)\, d\tau=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(t−\tau)\, d\tau={\sin(\pi t)\over \pi}u(t)={\sin(\pi t)\over \pi},\quad t>0.$$

I did the convolution integral here with *Mathematica* or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BCos%5BPi%20tau%5D%20UnitStep%5Bt%20-%20tau%5D,%20%7Btau,%200,%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D).

Answer (score 0):

The unit step function $u(\cdot)$ has the property that whenever what is inside those
parentheses is *positive*, the function has value $1$ while if what is inside those
parentheses is _negative, the function has value $0$.  Now, when you write
$$y(t) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(t−\tau)\, d\tau$$
you are finding the value of the output for a *fixed* value of of $t$, say $t=2.138$.
So now let us look at $u(2.138-\tau)$ as $\tau$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$.
That stuff inside the parentheses is going to have value $2.138 > 0$ at
$\tau = 0$, and also positive value **as long as** $\tau < 2.138$. Once $\tau$
sweeps past $2.138$, that stuff inside parentheses is going to be negative
and so $u(2.138-\tau)$ will have value $0$. So, we conclude that
$$y(2.138) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(2.138−\tau)\, d\tau
= \int_{0}^{2.138}\cos(\pi\tau)\cdot 1\, d\tau.$$
Repeating the same argument for $t=4.917$ we see that 
$$y(4.917) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(4.917−\tau)\, d\tau
= \int_{0}^{4.917}\cos(\pi\tau)\cdot 1\, d\tau.$$
After a few more attempts like this, a light will begin to shine 
in your head as you
shout "Hey, Ma, I think I am beginning to see a pattern here!"
and conclude that for *any* fixed positive real number $t$,
$$y(t) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\pi\tau)u(t−\tau)\, d\tau
= \int_{0}^{t}\cos(\pi\tau)\, d\tau.$$
I hope that you can evaluate that last integral without any
difficulty.